# How can I hide and scroll popup window in coc.nvim in Vim?

Tags: plugin-coc

How can I **scroll** and **hide** a floating window in Vim using the coc.nvim plugin?

I added these mappings to my `vim.rc` file but I still cannot manage it.
I would expect if I press `ctrl+f` once I have a floating window in `normal mode` then it scrolls or if I press my leader key `\ + h` then it hides it. What do I do wrong? Thank you!

```
nmap <silent> <leader>h <Plug>(coc-float-hide)

"coc#util#float_scroll({forward})
"Return expr for scrolling a floating window forward or backward. ex: >

nnoremap <expr><C-f> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
nnoremap <expr><C-b> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
```

[image]

Comment: I use vim 8 on Mac. I read this overlay must be a popup and does not have these commands.

Comment: Do note that vim.rc =/= vimrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a general way to scroll `popup` window <s>above or under</s> around cursor, it first get `winid` by test [:h popup_locate()](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_locate%28%29) with screen cursor position, then update `firstline` of the found window.

I didn't add the close map, AFAIK, it's closed automatically when you move your cursor.

Note that the beginning and ending of scroll is affected by [:h 'scrolloff'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27scrolloff%27)

**code update** :

- Removed hardcoded binding.
- Use `:h popup_getpos()` to get `firstline`, simplify scroll logic.
- Test entire rect instead of 2 corners in `find_cursor_popup()`.

**known issue**

- I use `<esc>` instead of `blank` as `no operation`, as `blank` doesn't trigger popup window redraw. `<esc>` will also trigger a `bell`, you may use `set belloff+=esc` to deal with it.

```
nnoremap <expr> <c-d> misc#popup#scroll_cursor_popup(1) ? '<esc>' : '<c-d>'
nnoremap <expr> <c-u> misc#popup#scroll_cursor_popup(0) ? '<esc>' : '<c-u>'

function misc#popup#find_cursor_popup(...)
  let radius = get(a:000, 0, 2)
  let srow = screenrow()
  let scol = screencol()

  " it's necessary to test entire rect, as some popup might be quite small
  for r in range(srow - radius, srow + radius)
    for c in range(scol - radius, scol + radius)
      let winid = popup_locate(r, c)
      if winid != 0
        return winid
      endif
    endfor
  endfor

  return 0
endfunction

function misc#popup#scroll_cursor_popup(down)
  let winid = misc#popup#find_cursor_popup()
  if winid == 0
    return 0
  endif

  let pp = popup_getpos(winid)
  call popup_setoptions( winid,
        \ {'firstline' : pp.firstline + ( a:down ? 1 : -1 ) } )

  return 1
endfunction
```

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/1160) about this.

Comment: This works. Only thing I had to update was the fn name ```s:find_cursor_popup```is ```scroll_popup``` in the key mappings. Amazing, many thanks!

Comment: Forgot to change `map`, Updated.

Comment: Thank you again

Comment: @Lajos The original script failed to locate popup in certain conditions, it's fixed now.

Comment: I got 2 errors after adding those lines to .vimrc.  ```E746: Function name does not match script file name: misc#popup#find_cursor_popup``` and ```E746: Function name does not match script file name: misc#popup#scroll_cursor_popup```

Comment: @sify Those names are `:h autoload` functions, you need to change it's name.

Comment: @dedowsd wdym change its name?